# unable to connect RDS MYSQL Database via AWS EC2 instance but its showing error ( mysql: command not found) Mysql is installed on instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[root@ip-172-31-31-124 ~]# mysql -h sonarqubedb123.cy68wpij5udn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u sonarqubedb123 -p
-bash: mysql: command not found
[root@ip-172-31-31-124 ~]# ^C
[root@ip-172-31-31-124 ~]#

Comment: Did you install mysql? What linux distro are you using?

Comment: I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely related to mysql not installed. Can you please run the below command to verify and confirm.

> mysql --version

**Below is sample output when mysql is installed.**

*ubuntu@ip-172-16-36-17:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*

You can install mysql client on Ubuntu distro with the following:

> apt-get install mysql-client

Command may be different if you are working on a different distro.